# Not sure how numerator changes in conditional probability question

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

$X \sim \exp(\lambda)$ and $P(X > x) = e^{-\lambda x}$

I need to calculate

$$P((k -1 )T < X \leq kT - u \mid (k -1 )T < X \leq kT$$

Which I thought became

$$\frac{P\{(k -1 )T < X \leq kT - u, (k -1 )T < X \leq kT\}}{P\{(k -1 )T < X \leq kT\}}$$

Which would then go to

$$\frac{\left( e^{-\lambda(k -1)T} -  e^{-\lambda (kT - u)} \right) \left(e^{-\lambda(kT)} -  e^{-\lambda (k - 1)T} \right)}{\left(e^{-\lambda(k-1)T} -  e^{-\lambda kT} \right)}$$

But as this would end up all just cancelling out, I checked the answers and they say it should be

$$\frac{e^{-\lambda(k -1)T} - e^{\lambda(kT - u)}}{e^{-\lambda(k-1)T} -  e^{-\lambda kT} }$$

What happens to the numerator then?

Comment: What precisely does "$PP(\lambda)$" mean?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't supposed to say $PP$, that was a different question I started writing up. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Hint: What is needed to justify expressing the probability of the conjunction of two events (the numerator in the fraction) as a product of two probabilities?  (I presume $0 \le u \lt T$, by the way, otherwise you're in trouble...)

Comment: Memoryless property. Dang. I thought of this last time!

Comment: It's more basic than that. It might help to draw pictures of the two events $(k-1)T \lt X \le kT-u$ and $(k-1)T \lt X \le kT$ on a number line.

Comment: Ohh. $((k - 1)T < X \leq kT - u) < ((k - 1)T < X \leq kT)$ so regardless of $(k - 1)T < X \leq kT$ happening, $(k - 1)T < X \leq kT$ will happen?

Comment: Hint: If $A \subset B$, then $$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}.$$